# Exception on temporary table - e11000 duplicate key error

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Salutations! Long time peruser, first time questioner. Hopefully I present the problem clearly.

I've run into some behavior I'm having trouble understanding with our MongoDB operations.

Our initial exposure to the problem came in the form of several MongoDB exception alerts when accessing one of our endpoints.

> Command aggregate failed: insert for $out failed: { lastOp: { ts: Timestamp(1612204536, 11872), t: 45 }, connectionId: 101263, err: "E11000 duplicate key error collection: qt.tmp.agg_out.7907 index: *id* dup key: { : "jLCJp53" }", code: 11000, codeName: "DuplicateKey", n: 0, ok: 1.0, operationTime: Timestamp(1612204536, 11872), $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1612204536, 11873), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }.

Looking into the endpoint, it calls a method to get the Requests collection like so. I believe the exception is throwing at the $out in this code block:

```
        public IEnumerable<Request> GetRequests(string courseId, string quizId = "", string questionId = "")
    {
        string tempColName = "tempQTCol-GetRequests-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmssfff") + "-" + courseId + "-" + H.GenerateUniqueId();
        var requests = GetCollection<Request>(CollectionName).Aggregate(new AggregateArgs
        {
            Pipeline = new[] {
               BsonDocument.Parse("{ $match: {   $and: [{ \"CourseId\": \"" + courseId
            + "\" }, { \"QuizId\": /.*" + quizId + ".*/i }, { \"QuestionId\": /.*" + questionId + ".*/i}] } }"),
               BsonDocument.Parse("{ $out : \""+tempColName+"\" }")
            }
        }).Select(s => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Request>(s)).ToList();
        DropCollection(tempColName);
        return requests;
    }
```

I don't know if it's helpful information, but as a consequence, since the error is being thrown before the DropCollection, I believe temporary collections are being created on our DB and never being dropped.

[temporary database creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRH0s.png)

In application insights, there are logs recording attempts to post to the endpoint, it throws a 500 error with the MongoDB exception I posted above.

Thanks in advance for time and consideration. I'm not very familiar with mongo, but I'll do my best to provide any information that's requested.

Answer (score 0):

You have the id dup key: { : "jLCJp53" }"   , you may need to drop your temporary collection every time before document insertion or alternatively you need to allow the _id key to be auto generated ( by default the auto-generated mongodb _id key is unique per process )